# Can I include php within an echo statement

Tags: php, smarty, heredoc

I'm probably being very inelegant about this - but I am new so figuring things out as best I can.

I'm dynamically generating a form using smarty tags.

Within a smarty tag I have

```
<<MY PHP>>
<<The HTML echod using heredoc syntax>>
```

I want to set the values of the form according to session variables, and so for example, want to put a

```
if($_SESSION['sv_02']=="2012") echo "selected";
```

to prepopulate a drop down menu according to the variable stored in SESSION.

**How can I include such a PHP command *within* my heredoc block. Is it possible?**

If this is an ass-backwards way of operating I'd also appreciate advice on that fron. Thanks very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why not do your logic for setting the variables first then the heredoc

```
if($_SESSION['sv_02']=="2012" $selected= "selected";


....

echo <<<EOT
---
--
$selected
---
EOT;
```

ALTERNATIVE

```
echo <<<EOT
---
--
EOT;

if($_SESSION['sv_02']=="2012" echo "selected";

echo <<<EOT
---
--
EOT;
```

Comment: Interesting... but I have several options within the selection element... each one needs "selected" echoing if and only if the session variable matches the name of that particular option?

Comment: I can see that would work - but be very painstaking in my case - I think I'll have to go back to basics of form generation via php - thanks very much for your input however.